# AJAX call returns a 500 error - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an ajax call from my view that triggers when i click on the upvote/downvote buttons (which should be a POST http request). However, AJAX is returning a internal 500 error (I presume that it is because there is no vote view file)

Controller file

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController


def vote
    PostsVote.create(
        user_id: session[:id],
        post_id: vote_params[:post_id].to_i,
        vote: vote_params[:vote].to_i)
    @post = Post.find(vote_params[:post_id])
    votes_total = @post.posts_votes.sum(:vote)
    {post_id: @post.id, votes: votes_total}.to_json
end

private

def vote_params
    params.permit(:post_id, :vote)
end
end
```

View file with AJAX

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Welcome to Hacker News Clone</h1>

<h3>All posts</h3>
<ul>
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <li id="post<%= post.id %>">
    <a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.post_desc %>
    </a>
    <br/>
    <span>
      <%= @post_votes[index] %> points
    </span>
      by <a href="/users/<%= post.user.id %>"><%= post.user.username %></a> | <%= post.comments.count %> comments
    <br/>
    <button <%= "disabled" if post.posts_votes.find_by(user_id: session[:id]) && post.posts_votes.find_by_user_id(session[:id]).vote == 1 %> class="upvote" data-post-id="<%= post.id %>" width="40px" height="40px">Upvote</button>
    <button <%= "disabled" if post.posts_votes.find_by(user_id: session[:id]) && post.posts_votes.find_by_user_id(session[:id]).vote == -1 %> class="downvote" data-post-id="<%= post.id %>" width="40px" height="40px">Downvote</button>


  </li>
  <br/>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Check if any post-vote combination for that user already exists and change upvote/downvote button to disabled


$(".upvote").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var postId = $(this).data("post-id");
var url = "/posts/" + postId + "/vote"
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {"post_id": postId,
           "vote": 1},
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(response){
    debugger
    $("#post" + response["post_id"] + " span").text(response["votes"] + " points");
    $("#post" + response["post_id"] + " button" + ".upvote").attr("disabled", "disabled")
});
});

$(".downvote").on("click", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var postId = $(this).data("post-id");
var url = "/posts/" + postId + "/vote"
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {"post_id": postId,
           "vote": -1},
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function(response){
    $("#post" + response["post_id"] + " span").text(response["votes"] + " points");
    $("#post" + response["post_id"] + " button" + ".downvote").attr("disabled", "disabled")
});
});


});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your log file (`log/development.log`). You can follow the log with `$ tail -f log/development.log` in unix based systems. Also you can check the body of the response in the web inspector. Rails includes a helpful error message in the development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; you're getting the error because Rails is trying to render the vote view, which doesn't exist. Since you didn't call `render` or `redirect_to` in the `vote` action, Rails by default tries to render the template.

It looks like you just want to respond with JSON, which you can do like this:

```
def vote
  PostsVote.create(
      user_id: session[:id],
      post_id: vote_params[:post_id].to_i,
      vote: vote_params[:vote].to_i)

  @post = Post.find(vote_params[:post_id])
  votes_total = @post.posts_votes.sum(:vote)

  render json: {post_id: @post.id, votes: votes_total} # to_json is called automatically
end
```

I've made the assumption that this action is always called via Ajax and always wants to return JSON. If you are going to have multiple types of responses, you'll need a `respond_to` block. [Here's an example with `respond_to` from the official guides.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data)